# How can I see both the plain text and the html versions of email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, html-email, email-client

I've developing the part of a Ruby on Rails app that send out emails.

I've created two docs for the two different output formats - plain text and html.

How can I adjust my email client (e.g. gmail) to show each of the formats - both, one after the other, or just one but specify which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gmail you can do this by clicking on the little arrow next to the reply button. In the menu that the arrow opens, click "Show Original". [Source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/gmail-view-raw-email-message/)